# Putting Text on Three Images In A Single Row HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, image

I would like to have a single row of three images, with 1 line of text on each, but am unable to find a way to do it. I am reasonably new to HTML and CSS.

```html
<div style="width: 100%;" class="images">
  <img src="FullSizeRender.png" alt="crossSection" style="max-width: 20%;">
  <h4>Text</h4>
  <img src="FullSizeRender.png" alt="crossSection" style="max-width: 20%;">
  <h4>Text</h4>
  <img src="FullSizeRender.png" alt="crossSection" style="max-width: 20%;">
  <h4>Text</h4>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want picture with text - use `<figure>`. See [this codepen](https://codepen.io/fen1x/pen/VrMadN)

Answer (score 2):

You should either use `background` or `position: absolute` to get your text on top of the images.

Here is an example using `background`:

```css
.columnContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.imageContainer {
  flex-basis: 33%;
  text-align: center;
  background: url('http://imgsv.imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/df/img/sample/img_01.jpg') top no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="columnContainer">
  <div class="imageContainer">
    <h4>Text</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="imageContainer">
    <h4>Text</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="imageContainer">
    <h4>Text</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Explanations:

*Q: What are we doing?*

1. First, we make our three-column style with `display: flex;`:

   ```
   .columnContainer {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: row;
   }
   .imageContainer {
     flex-basis: 33%;
   }
   ```
2. then, we set the background-image on the `div` using:

   ```
   background: url('http://imgsv.imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/df/img/sample/img_01.jpg') top no-repeat;
   ```
3. next, we tell it to either cover or fill the div with:

   ```
   background-size: cover; /*or contain, that's up to you*/
   ```

Here you go :)

---

See some references below:

- [CSS Background - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background)
- [background-size - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)
- [Flexbox, complete guide - CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Thanks very much. Works with the image provided, but not with my image. Do I need to use a full file path?

Comment: You are free to choose between absolute and relative path, maybe take a look at http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/

Comment: I can't get the file path to work, so is there a way to make this possible?                                                                                                              `<div class="columnContainer">
  <div class="imageContainer">
    <h4>Text</h4>
    <img src="FullSizeRender.png" alt="hello" style="max-width: 33%; max-height: 33%;">
  </div>
  </div>`